# JPA - select with join - how to make two related tables

Tags: select, jpa, join, jpql

I have two tables with relacionship by id_employee.

```
---------------------------       ---------------------------
table employee                      table timesheet
---------------------------       ---------------------------
id_employee                        id_time
name_employee                      date_entry
---------------------------        quant_hour
                                   id_employee
                                  ---------------------------
```

I need to do a select that returns all records from the table employe and hours in existing related table timesheet. Some employees do not have hours recorded in the timesheet table but should appear in the list because they are registered in the employee table.

What the JPQL query for this ?

Class Employee

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id_employee;
private String name_employee ;

    //GETS and SETS
}
```

Class TimeSheet

```
@Entity
public class Timesheet {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id_time;
private Double quant_hour;
    private Date date_entry;
@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;  

    //GETS and SETS
}
```

Comment: It depends on your entites more than on your tables, since JPQL operates on the entites. Please post the ralavant Employee and the Timesheet class code (only attributes and annotations, not gettes/setters)

Comment: update the ask... include the classes !

Answer (score 0):

Provided that both tables are mapped correctly,the Employee entity will have an attribute (or collection) of type Timesheet entity, therefore, you only need to get the list of employees:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e
```

JPA automatically retrieves the Timesheet (or list of Timesheets) when you want to read it from the Employee entity.